# Grails Integration test: Failure...Cannot invoke method addToPosts() on null object

Tags: grails, groovy

:D
I was following a tutorial in a book, and I did follow it thoroughly.
However, come the part where I am supposed to write an integration test, it suddenly failed saying: `Cannot invoke method addToPosts() on null object` right after I ran the test. I wonder, what could be wrong... :| Please help! :) Below is the code for the test:

```
void testFirstPost() {
   def user = new User(userID: 'joemillan', password:'youaretheonly',
                       homepage: 'www.geeee.com').save()

   def post = new Post (content: 'hellloo oasdo sjdosa daodkao ')
   user.addToPosts(post)

   assertEquals 1, User.get(user.id).posts.size()
}
```

Here is the user class:

```
class User {

   String userID
   String password
   String homepage

   Profile profile

   static hasMany=[posts:Post, tags:Tag]

   static constraints = {
      userID (unique: true, size: 6..20)
      password (size: 6..20, validator:{password,userID-> return password !=userID.userID}) //validator = The password must not match the username.
      homepage (url:true, nullable: true)
      profile (nullable: true)
   }
}
```

Here is the Post class:

```
class Post {

   String content
   Date dateCreated

   static constraints = {
      content (blank:false)
   }

   static belongsTo = [user:User]
   static hasMany = [tags:Tag]

   static mapping = {
      sort dateCreated: "desc"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`save()` returns null if validation fails, and "www.geeee.com" isn't a valid URL. It would work with "http://www.geeee.com".

But you should split the creation and saving into 2 steps so you can check it:

```
def user = new User(userID: 'joemillan', password:'youaretheonly',
                    homepage: 'www.geeee.com')
user.save()
assertFalse user.hasErrors()
```

or use failOnError if you are confident that that part should succeed and only want to test the other parts, e.g.

```
def user = new User(userID: 'joemillan', password:'youaretheonly',
                    homepage: 'www.geeee.com').save(failOnError: true)
```

Comment: BTW... Failures mean that the test failed, while errors have something to do with the code of my test, am I right?

Comment: `def user = new User(userID: 'joemillan', password:'youaretheonly',
                    homepage: 'www.geeee.com').save(failOnError: true)` 
is kinda like what I saw on the bootstrap tutorial!! :D